# How to set smerge-command-prefix to "\C-cv"

Tags: key-bindings, magit

I find the default prefix for smerge-mode `C-c^` and I have following setup:

```
(setq smerge-command-prefix "\C-cv")
(setq smerge-command-prefix "\C-c\C-v")
```

Also `C-c ^` runs the command icicle-search-keywords (found in icicle-mode-map), so its prefix is overwritten by icicle.

But when I try them, still they are undefined:

```
C-c C-v is undefined
C-c v is undefined
```

Is there any way to force to set operation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*First:* a variable can not have two different values at the same time.

> (setq smerge-command-prefix "\C-cv")
> (setq smerge-command-prefix "\C-c\C-v")

*Second:* to use this prefix the above variable has to be set before `smerge-mode` is loaded. So either ensure that `(setq smerge-command-prefix "\C-cv")` is eval'd  before you use (or `require`) `smerge-mode` the first time. Or set and save this variable through `customize` and restart emacs.

Or you could simply use

```
(eval-after-load 'smerge-mode
  (lambda ()
    (define-key smerge-mode-map (kbd "C-c v") smerge-basic-map)
    (define-key smerge-mode-map (kbd "C-c C-v") smerge-basic-map)))
```

*note:* I got most of that information by looking at smerge-mode's source code.

Comment: Now it says `C-c C-v runs the command elpy-check` in a python file :-(

Comment: I have no idea why it should say `elpy-check`. Nevertheless, try the `eval-after-load` it is better than the original  global keybinding.

Comment: I was able to make it work using this approach (https://stackoverflow.com/a/683575/2402577) ; I have no idea why some keys were overwritten by `elpy`